# Gcc Error Trying to PIP Install Fasttext Redhat (Amazon ec2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, pip, fasttext

Simply I am getting this error:

```
gcc: error: fasttext/fasttext.c: No such file or directory

gcc: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

Trying to run command: `sudo pip install fasttext`

Server info:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09
```

Comment: I'm having the same error on my Mac OSX laptop. Have you found a solution?